# When was the last time the Lions and Browns both won on the same weekend?

Tags: trivia, american-football

When was the last time the Lions and Browns both won on the same weekend? They both won on September 23rd, 2018, but they are notorious for being the two 0-16 teams in NFL history.

Answer (score 1):

Same week: The weekend of November 9, 2014

- Browns over the Bengals 24-3 (Thursday Night, 11/6/2014) [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201411060cin.htm)
- Lions over the Dolphis 20-16 (Sunday, 11/9/2014) [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201411090det.htm)

Same weekend (day): October 26, 2014

- Browns over the Raiders 23-13 [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201410260cle.htm)
- Lions over the Falcons 22-21 [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201410260atl.htm)