# When was the last time the Bills, Lions, Browns, & Jets won on the same day?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

On October 6, 2018, the Bills, Lions, Browns and Jets all won. When was the last time the Bills, Lions, Browns, & Jets won on the same day? Or even the same week?

Answer (score 2):

Using Pro Football Reference's [Team Game Finder](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=2012&year_max=2012&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&temperature_gtlt=lt&game_result=W&c5val=1.0&order_by=game_date) with the query: "In a single game, in 2012, in the Regular Season, team won game, sorted by descending Date," the answer is October 14, 2012.

- Jets over Colts 35-9 [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201210140nyj.htm)
- Lions over Eagles 26-23 [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201210140phi.htm)
- Browns over Bengals 34-24 [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201210140cle.htm)
- Bills over Cardinals 19-16 [Box Score](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201210140crd.htm)

Comment: While I'm in no way disputing this, could you add some details as to how you obtained this information?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I elaborated how I got to my answer. [This answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/20259) to a similar question gave me a starting point and I just went through the seasons from there.